# Why didn't Yitzhak bless Eisav the same way he blessed Yaakov?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-toldot

Why couldn't Yitzhak make the same blessing twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yitzchok told him in 27:37 that he already made Yaakov the master, so he can't give that to Eisav. He already gave Yaakov control over grain and wine, so it's too late for that as well. But of dew and fertility of the earth there is an abundance. Of that he was able to bless Esav.

Answer (score 0):

Also refer to [Bereishis Rabbah 99:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.99.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) where it says that Yitzchak loved him and did want to bless Esav and not only that, but to even reveal the end of the galus!! Hashem resultantly removed Yitzchak's wisdom so he did not know what to do and instead was left in a state of terror, and that is what is meant when it says "וַיֶּחֱרַד יִצְחָק" - "And Yitzchak trembled".